# Integrating Python back-end with HTML/CSS/JS User Interface for desktop applications?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, user-interface

How could I or would it be appropriate to integrate Python code with HTML/CSS/JS as the user interface in creating desktop applications. A simple example; if I wanted to created a function with Python that prints "Hello World!" and use HTML/CSS/JS to create a user interface (make it fancy, perhaps add some images), so I can use it as a desktop application. How would I go about this?

I understand I could use libraries such as Tkinter, but it doesn't allow the flexibility of customising user interface.

I've read about using Electron, but I haven't seen many people using Python as the back-end. Any help or information in relation to using Python as a back-end with HTML/CSS/JS as the user interface will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know you tagged this question with Java, but [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a popular python web framework.

Comment: My mistake, it was suppose to be Javascript.

Comment: `Python as a back-end`, are you referring to web framework or desktop application ? because you asked `user interface in creating desktop applications`

Comment: More specifically as a desktop application, using Python as a back-end. Is it called GUI for desktop applications, not UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best option is to look at Flask (Almost no learning curve) as a backend and you can continue using HTML/CSS/JS as frontend.

However to create a desktop application you will need to integrate (Your frontend) with tools like electron.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've definitely heard about Flask in the past, what is the main difference between using Flask instead of Python as a back-end? Also, when creating the desktop application, I add both the back-end (flask) and front-end into one, singular Electron app? I was looking at one of the simple Electron app's repository and there seem to only be a html, javascript, css and json file, what serves as the back-end for this particular application? (the app was converting letter input into hash values) Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, Flask is a library to help you use python as a backend easily. You add the backend on a web server (server-side) and you package HTML + CSS + JS with electron and you create your required desktop apps (Client Side). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, you explained it well. I understand it now.

Comment: I am glad I could help you. It would be great if you could mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to choose framework of python. like Django etc. Then you can make own desktop application as you can.

Comment: With the tutorials I've been following, they refer to Django as a framework to create websites and web apps. Could I use it to create Python-based desktop applications as well?

Comment: Sorry dude, My english is not good. But you can make desktop applications using python.

Comment: That is fine. Thanks for your recommendation.